# twitter connection failed

Tags: android, ssl, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

**In Android**,
Twitter connection failed. SSL is required?

My code was working perfectly and it is currently a live application. However, since 2014  it hasn't been working and I've heard that Twitter has applied https or using SSL concept.

**help me to solved this issue.**

**Here is my log.**

```
 03-14 15:00:02.838: D/TwitterApp(697): Error getting access token
03-14 15:00:02.878: W/System.err(697): 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
03-14 15:00:02.878: W/System.err(697): message - SSL is required
03-14 15:00:02.878: W/System.err(697): code - 92
03-14 15:00:02.878: W/System.err(697): Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
03-14 15:00:02.878: W/System.err(697):  http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=6f0f59ca or
03-14 15:00:02.888: W/System.err(697):  http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=20d0f73f
03-14 15:00:02.888: W/System.err(697): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[6f0f59ca-20d0f73f], statusCode=403, message=SSL is required, code=92, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=RateLimitStatusJSONImpl{remaining=14, limit=15, resetTimeInSeconds=1394790328, secondsUntilReset=-18874}, version=3.0.3}
03-14 15:00:02.888: W/System.err(697):  at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:177)
03-14 15:00:02.888: W/System.err(697):  at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
03-14 15:00:02.888: W/System.err(697):  at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:89)
03-14 15:00:02.888: W/System.err(697):  at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.fillInIDAndScreenName(TwitterBaseImpl.java:126)
03-14 15:00:02.888: W/System.err(697):  at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.verifyCredentials(TwitterImpl.java:592)
03-14 15:00:02.908: W/System.err(697):  at com.twitter.android.TwitterApp$3.run(TwitterApp.java:150)
```

**twitter connection code**.
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/ this is a develop

Comment: check: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/

Comment: still not solved please help me out.

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge nothing much has changed with the OAuth implementation that would cause this, however, after you have authenticated using OAuth if you were then using non-SSL requests for data this may have worked previously but would not now. Twitter introduced a change [restricting access to SSL/TLS connections only](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/24239) on January 14th 2014.

Somewhere in your Java code there will be URL's that are being used to retrieve data from Twitter's servers. I would suggest you do a search/replace through your code, where for any occurrences of `http://api.twitter.com/` you replace them with `https://api.twitter.com/` and this may hopefully solve this issue. It's possible there are other issues that may come to light afterwards but at least this is your first step.

By specifying `https` this makes sure you are using SSL protocol to ensure data is kept secure during transmission between your application and Twitter.

If you need more information to optionally validate and verify the SSL certificate in your code for additional security, then read [Connecting to Twitter API via SSL](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/security/using-ssl) on Twitter's developers documentation website.

---

*Edit:* Just to clarify further, in order to receive this error message you must have successfully authenticated using OAuth via an SSL URL, but then reverted to non-SSL URL's for follow-on data requests.

Comment: in my application there is no any url like "http://api.twitter.com/"

for twitter conncetion below three url i have used.
1)https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token
2)https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token
3)https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize

what actually happens like i am successfully loged-in but at last it will show me message. "twitter conncetion failed".

Comment: That is your problem, twitter is tightening down their infrastructure and removing endpoints that are valid. For api calls you may have succeeded in going straight to twitter.com in the past, but you were supposed to go to api.twitter.com. You need to fix all your urls.

Comment: My code was working perfectly. suddenly its not working.

Comment: This is an issue you may face again in future @bhavesh-jethani. Since your code is dependent on Twitter's API you will have to frequently check the [link]Twitter Developers Website (https://dev.twitter.com/)[/link] for any changes that they make to their API or service which could impact your implementation code. It's not unusual for API improvements and security enhancements to not be backwards-compatible, and even if for a period of time multiple versions of an API are published to allow for a transition period, eventually the older versions will normally be discontinued after a while.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using sign-post + Twitter4j, you'd define your OAuth providers as follows:

```
private DefaultOAuthConsumer mOAuthConsumer = null;
private DefaultOAuthProvider httpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
        "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
        "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
```

then perform user authentication:

```
private void getTwitterAuthorisation() {
    if (backend.hasNetworkConnection(this, true)) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mOAuthConsumer = newOAuthConsumer();
                    String authUrl = httpOauthprovider.retrieveRequestToken(mOAuthConsumer, CALLBACK);
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "getTwitterAuthorisation()", e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

then obtain the tokens:

```
TwitterCredentials creds = null;
            try {
                httpOauthprovider.retrieveAccessToken(mOAuthConsumer, verifier);
                final String token = mOAuthConsumer.getToken();
                final String secret = mOAuthConsumer.getTokenSecret();
                final AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(token, secret);
                final Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
                twitter.setOAuthConsumer(mOAuthConsumer.getConsumerKey(), mOAuthConsumer.getConsumerSecret());
                twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
                final long twitterId = twitter.getId();
                final String twitterScreenName = twitter.getScreenName();
                creds = new TwitterCredentials();
                creds.oauthToken = token;
                creds.oauthSecret = secret;
                creds.twitterId = twitterId;
                creds.screenName = twitterScreenName;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "doTwitterConnect", e);
            }
            return creds;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error and upgrading to the latest version of twitter4j 3.0.5 ,fixed the issue.

Get the latest here http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html#download

I should mention that the version i was running was twitter4j 3.0.3. going to version 3.0.5 or 3.0.6 fixed the issue for me.